# How can I write a Multipart entity into a file when using Retrofit/OkHttp?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I am updating code that was originally built with the Apache HTTP Client to use Retrofit instead.  The chunk of code that I'm having troubles with uploads a copy of the local app database to my server.  Part of this process is using the md5 of what is being sent in the POST authentication.  It first creates the multipart entity then writes it into a new file so the md5 can be made on that file.

```
public class MyRestClient extends AsyncHttpClient {

 public void sendBackup(String secretKey, String accessId, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler){

    File file = new File(FileUtil.DATBASE_DIRECTORY_PATH + File.separator + FileUtil.DATABASE_FILE_NAME + ".db");
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE, boundary, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);
    entity.addPart("device_backup[database_dump]", fileBody);


    //creating this dummy file is crucial because for the server to authorize this file the
    //server takes the md5 of the raw_post of the request and compares it to the md5 in the header
    //this dummy file is mimicking the request.raw_post that is done on the server
    File dummyFile = new File(FileUtil.DATBASE_DIRECTORY_PATH + File.separator + "dummy.db");
    try {

      if (!dummyFile.exists()) {
        dummyFile.createNewFile();
      }

      FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(dummyFile);
      entity.writeTo(fileOutputStream);

      fileOutputStream.flush();
      fileOutputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    setAuth(DEVICE_BACKUP_EXTENSION, dummyFile, secretKey, accessId);

    super.post(MyApplication.getContext(), DEVICE_BACKUP_URL, entity, MultipartContentType, responseHandler);
  }
}
```

What I have so far:

```
public void backupCurrentDatabase(final Long backupId) {

    public static String boundary = "*****";
    public static final String MultipartContentType = "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + 
        boundary + "; charset=UTF-8";

    SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Const.SHARE_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String accessId = prefs.getString(Const.ACCESS_ID_PREF_KEY, null);
    String secretKey = prefs.getString(Const.SECRET_KEY_PREF_KEY, null);
    File file = new File(FileUtil.DATBASE_DIRECTORY_PATH + File.separator + FileUtil.DATABASE_FILE_NAME + ".db");

    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("device_backup[database_dump]", FileUtil.DATABASE_FILE_NAME + ".db",
                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(MultipartContentType), file))
            .build();

    File dummyFile = new File(FileUtil.DATBASE_DIRECTORY_PATH + File.separator + "dummy.db");
    try {

      if (!dummyFile.exists()) {
        dummyFile.createNewFile();
      }

      FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(dummyFile);
      //Write requestBody to dummyFile

      fileOutputStream.flush();
      fileOutputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SyncApi client = ServiceGenerator.createService(SyncApi.class, ServiceGenerator.DEVICE_BACKUP_EXTENSION,
            dummyFile, secretKey, accessId);
    Call<SendBackup> call = client.sendBackup(requestBody);
  }
```

So I take the same pieces of information and make a RequestBody that can be passed through Retrofit.  It seems like this should be what I write to the dummyFile.  Next is the same code for writing the Multipart to dummyFile, except it's missing the important part of actually writing to the fileOutputStream because I don't know what function to use.  Next, set up the Retrofit instance and pass all the authentication information to my service generator.  Last make a call and pass the requestBody to Retrofit.  (call.enqueue() stuff not shown)

What am I missing to make this work?  Is a RequestBody even the right thing to be using?

Answer (score 0):

```
 /**
 * Upload picture API method.
 * This upload picture feature is only for demo purpose.
 */
public void UploadPictureToServer()
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        final APIParameters parameters = new APIParameters(MainActivity.this,true,false);
        Call<ResponseBody> call = parameters.GetUploadImageParameters(file);
        if (call == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

                parameters.DismissLoader();
                GetUploadImageData(response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

                parameters.DismissLoader();
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}

/**
 * Get Upload image response for parsing data
 * @param response
 */
private void GetUploadImageData(Response<ResponseBody> response)
{
    String MyResult = null;
    try
    {
        MyResult = CM.GetAPIResponseStatus(response.body().string(),MainActivity.this);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (MyResult == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    ArrayList<Model_Category> model_categoryArrayList = JSONHelper.parseUploadImageResponse(MyResult);
    if (model_categoryArrayList != null)
    {
     /*   try
        {
            CacheMemory.writeObject(MainActivity.this, "category.txt", model_categoryArrayList);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
        for (int i=0;i<model_categoryArrayList.size();i++)
        {
            Log.e("Category :-->","Id : "+model_categoryArrayList.get(i).id+" Name : "+model_categoryArrayList.get(i).categoryName);
        }
    }
}
```

> API Interface

```
/**
 * If you do not need any type-specific response, you can specify return value as simply Call<ResponseBody>.
 * @param image
 * @param //name
 * @return
 */
@Multipart
@POST(URLS.WEB_ADD_CATEGORY)
Call<ResponseBody> postImage(@Query(WebServicesTags.TAG_STR_APIKEY) String apiKey,@Part MultipartBody.Part image,@Part("userId") RequestBody userId,@Part("categoryName") RequestBody categoryName,@Part("deviceType") RequestBody deviceType,@Part("deviceToken") RequestBody deviceToken,@Part("accessToken") RequestBody accessToken,@Part("intUdId") RequestBody intUdId);
```